# How do I stop bootstrap from adding 'http://' to the beginning of a link path?

Tags: hyperlink, react-router, react-bootstrap, nav

The bootstrap collapsing navbar links adds "http://" to my link path and it makes the link not work in several browsers. (sit is on surge.sh)

Ok, I'm using react-bootstrap and react-router on my site.
I am deploying to surge.sh for testing purposes.
If I put a normal react-router link like this on the page:

```
<Link to="/contact" className="link">Contact</Link>
```

, the link works fine. I check the URL at the top of Safari and it reads:
binginlay.surge.sh

In my bootstrap navbar code I have links like this for he dropdown:

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="xl" bg="{background-color}" variant="dark" id="mobile">
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" id="menuButtonIcon" />
        <div id="mobileTitle">
            <div>Bingham Inlay Arts</div>
        </div>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="dropdownLinks">
                <Nav.Link href="/" id="galleryLink">Gallery</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/custom" id="customLink">Custom</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/videos" id="videosLink">Videos</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/techniques" id="tecniquesLink">Tecniques</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/bio" id="bioLink">Biography</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/contact" id="contactLink">Contact</Nav.Link>
             </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

The navbar hamburger icon shows up. When clicked, the dropdown menu appears. All the links are shown. Clicking a link give a surge.sh error 'Page not found'.
I check the URL at the top of Safari and it reads:
http://binginlay.surge.sh

The only difference between the link working and not is having the 'http://" added in front of the href link I provided.

How do I get bootstrap to not put 'http://' in front of my links?
Or, is there a workaround anyone can think of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "http" is not the problem, the problem is a badly configured server. Note that if you go directly to e.g. http://binginlay.surge.sh/custom it'll show a 404 page as well. See https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing for how to set it up for single page apps.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I very much appreciate it.